# Why isn't my append function working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this function to add the font awesome element to the nav element but nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

```
$("#Menu_list").append("<i class="fa fa-briefcase fa-fw"></i>");
```

The page loads but deletes the body for some reason. Here's the top of my code. Maybe i didn't close something.

```
$("#Menu_list").append("<i class="fa fa-briefcase fa-fw"></i>");

$("head link[rel='stylesheet']").last().after("<link rel='stylesheet' href='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' type='text/css' media='screen'>");
```

Comment: For a start you're not escaping your strings right...

Comment: Do you not get syntax highlighting at your end? I would say it's highlighting the problem pretty well

Comment: Why would you want to load css like that?

Comment: im not using a code editor unfortunately.. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape your quotes or use a combination of single and double.

This:

```
$("#Menu_list").append("<i class="fa fa-briefcase fa-fw"></i>");
```

Needs to be this:

```
$("#Menu_list").append('<i class="fa fa-briefcase fa-fw"></i>');
```

Comment: Thanks buddy it worked... still trying to get a hang of js!

Comment: No worries. If this has solved the problem you can mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: will do! in 7 minutes.. can't do it yet :)

Answer (score 1):

## Learn

[Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) in JavaScript are written with either single-quotes (`'`) or double-quotes (`"`)

```
var string1 = 'This is a string'
var string2 = "This is also a string"
```

If your string contains double-quotes, you must either escape them with a backslash (`\`):

```
var quote = "this string contains a \"quote\""
console.log(quote) // this string contains a "quote"
```

Or use single quotes:

```
var quote = 'this string contains a "quote"'
```

## Fix

```
$("#Menu_list").append('<i class="fa fa-briefcase fa-fw"></i>')
// or
$("#Menu_list").append("<i class=\"fa fa-briefcase fa-fw\"></i>")
```